# Hibernate 3 - 5 Migration. Org.hibernate.Criteria: Changing createCriteria(String association, String alias) to standard JPA using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, migration, hibernate-criteria

So I have this Hibernate Criteria code I want to change using JPA, I have made changes to it referenced below but I can't seem to find a replacement to creating a Criteria from "detCrit" with the method detCrit.createCriteria(String association, String alias) using JPA's CriteriaBuilder. if anyone knows an alternative solution I will be grateful.

```
\\\Initial Hibernate Criteria code

Criteria deCrit = currentSession().createCriteria(first.class, "firstbasic");
Criteria secondThemeCrit = detCrit.createCriteria("secondBasic","sc");
Criteria thirdThemeCrit = secondThemeCrit.createCriteria("thirdBasic");
```

```
\\\Partially changed code with JPA

CriteriaBuilder builder = Session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<First> deCrit = builder.createQuery(First.class);
Root<First> first = detCrit.from(First.class);
first.alias("firstbasic");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you use this code afterwards, but I assume within a subquery? If so, you can correlate the root in the subquery and the just call join on the correlated object which should result in the same:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = Session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<First> deCrit = builder.createQuery(First.class);
Root<First> first = detCrit.from(First.class);
Subquery<Integer> subquery = deCrit.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<First> correlatedFirst = subquery.correlate(first);
Join<First, Second> second = correlatedFirst.join("second");
```